# load jquery datepicker in subpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to load a subpage with a datepicker in a div on my mainpage but my datepicker won't work.

This is my script

```
 $(function(){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });

        function loadTherapie(){
            var therapieID = document.getElementById("lijstTherapieen").value;
            $("#divTherapie").load("wijzigtherapiesubpage.php?therapieID="+therapieID+"&cacheOntloper="+randomNumber()+"&type=2", function(response){
            $(response).find("datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        }
```

The function loadTherapie is called by the onchange event of a select.

And this is the code on my subpage

```
<form method="post" action="updateTherapie.php?type=2" name="therapie">     
    <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="txtdatumOpmaak" value="00-00-0000"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your lijstTherapieen,divTherapie ids in your html

Comment: lijstTherapieeen is a select in my main html page and divTherapie is a div in my main html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your selector :

```
function loadTherapie(){
        var therapieID = document.getElementById("lijstTherapieen").value;
        $("#divTherapie").load("wijzigtherapiesubpage.php?therapieID="+therapieID+"&cacheOntloper="+randomNumber()+"&type=2", function(response){
        //just mactch all the class datepicker
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    }
```